# Can I upload an entire folder with php?

Tags: php, file, upload, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to upload folder with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008406/how-to-upload-folder-with-php)

I know we can upload single or multiple files. But I want to select the entire directory. Is it possible?

Comment: Upload from where ? from a client using a browser ? or using PHP and CURL perhaps ? or something else ? what have you attempted so far ? anything ? your question as it stands lacks any kind of detail and is likely to be closed any minute ...

Comment: If all else fails, you could just zip it up first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is serverside, and the program uploading stuff is the browser.  The correct question is "Can a browser upload a whole folder?".  And the reply is: most browsers are programed to upload single files.. but It would be possible to write a browser to tar.gz a folder, and upload that file.

The protocol as not limitation on how much files attachements are uploaded.

Other related protocol is webdav...