# How to upload files with their folder?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a folder which has bunch of files.

I use below code to upload multiple files:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

It works fine but it does not upload parent folder why? I also want to upload the folder which files belong.

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429960/file-upload-and-knowing-the-directory-structure]

Comment: I am already doing this. What I want is to upload parent folder too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "upload" parent folder, but there is another way you can do it.

You can have a user enter the name of the folder into a text box:
`<input type='text' name='folder_name' placeholder='Enter Folder Name..' required />`

Then in your upload script use:

```
$dirName = $db->real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['folder_name'])));
if(!is_dir($dirName)){
   mkdir($dirName);
}

foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $dirName.$name))
}
```