# Upload directory doesn't send folder name with file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I tried new feature of directory upload https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218074/2004910 but I am not receiving exact folder structure on the server request.

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="files" class="file" type="file" name="file[]"  webkitdirectory directory>
<input type="submit" />
```

**Request Payload (network panel)**

[image]

**ExpressJS:**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var fs = require('fs');
//...
app.use(busboy()); 

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/files/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.redirect('back');
        });
    });
})
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Please suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "exact folder structure"?

Comment: folder structure is private to user. You'll only receive the files, not their location on the user's computer

Comment: @guest271314 It means that if files are arranged inside sub-folders..I need that information as well so that I can replicate same folder structure on server. It doesn't mean that I need full path from user's computer but should be relative to the folder being uploaded.

Comment: See [jQuery File Upload Plugin: Is possible to preserve the structure of uploaded folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106121/jquery-file-upload-plugin-is-possible-to-preserve-the-structure-of-uploaded-fol/), [How to upload and list directories at firefox and chrome/chromium using change and drop events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664662/how-to-upload-and-list-directories-at-firefox-and-chrome-chromium-using-change-a)

Comment: @guest271314 Please suggest how to send that to server once created same structure using your post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106121/jquery-file-upload-plugin-is-possible-to-preserve-the-structure-of-uploaded-fol/

Comment: You can create a `JSON` string reflecting the structure of the directories and files using pattern at second link at previous comment. Note, the `TODO` at code where a directory contains both files and nested directories.

Comment: What is the difference between the directory structure received at server and actual directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory

> After the user makes a selection, each File object in files has its
>   `File.webkitRelativePath` property set to the relative path within the
>   selected directory at which the file is located.

I do not think it is passed in the POST request tough, you'll have to work it on the client side I think.

```
$('#files').on('change',function(e){
    var files = e.target.files;
    for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var path = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
        $('#form').append('<input type="hidden" name="filepath[]" value="'+path+'"/>');
    }
});
```

This script will append hidden inputs to send the file paths with the POST. Your script could then use it. Look out tough, if I sent you a file with the same filename, but in two different folders, you might not place the right one in the correct folder.

Comment: That's the question..How to pass that information on server? What sort of arrangements needed on client side for this.

Comment: As of now, without making any changes to my javascript/html code, I am getting list of all files..and I need folder structure which is not being received at server but being passed into request payload.